# Can I have multiple ini config files in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, ini, paster, python-paste

I'd like an equivalent of the [Django One True Way](https://speakerdeck.com/jacobian/the-best-and-worst-of-django?slide=81) settings layout: a shared base file, and then a production file and a development file, each of which import the shared base.

Is this possible with Pyramid's config?

Comment: Please also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089479/how-to-use-a-common-ini-configuration-between-development-and-production-in-py

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes that's possible. In one of my projects I have a `production_base.ini` file and all other production inis inherit from it:

`production_base.ini`

```
[app:main]
use = egg:xxx
maintenance_mode = False
```

`production_www.ini`

```
[app:main]
use = config:production_base.ini
maintenance_mode = True  # overwrites the value in the base ini
```

You can also check [paste docs](http://pastedeploy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=config%3A#applications) for more examples.

Side note - you can't inherit logging section though.

Comment: Is there a way to refer to .ini file inside another package using `config`?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, `config.registry.settings['somevar']`. You can see more [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html#adding-a-custom-setting). Or did you mean using `config` within a .ini file?

Comment: @matino Can you explain your side note, "_you can't inherit logging section_", please? There is no mention about that in the [PasteDeploy docs](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/) and the [Pyramid logging docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/logging.html). The whole logging configuration is a scattered list of several sections, which is a pain to maintain in several ini-files. The perfect candidate for inheritance.

Comment: I can confirm @matino's side note: `use =` will not work in the sections related to logging. The [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module will raise a `KeyError` for keys you'd expect to be imported (e.g. `keys`, `class`). Looks like the inheritance is a PasteDeploy feature, and not generally supported in `.ini` files.