# Managing Pyramid configuration files efficiently

Tags: pyramid, paster, python-paste

Currently I am having `production.ini`, `develop.ini` and `test.ini` for a web application. Most of the INI configuration is copy-paste. I'd like to split off the shared configuration part to `base.ini` or similar.

How Pyramid configuration files can be extended or included in a way that the extension mechanism plays well with `pserve` and ofter serving strategies.

Comment: Hi Mikko. This question was recently asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258175/can-i-have-multiple-ini-config-files-in-pyramid

Comment: For some reason, the other question isn't as easily searchable as yours, so I'd prefer if you kept yours open as well.